# SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed Unable to load configuration. - action - file:

Tags: struts2, weblogic

I am new to work with Struts2 (version struts-2.3.4, i use all the dependency jars). I have developed an application and trying to deploy the same in Weblogic 9.2 server. It shows the error " SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed Unable to load configuration. - action - file" followed by the lines i have pasted

This code works in Jboss but not in Weblogic. So, what could be the mistake? and what is the solution for this?

```
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/users/capstat/tiv/bea/user_projects/domains/UATTIV/autodeploy/xmlconversion.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:19:57
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:309)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.loadFilter(FilterManager.java:88)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.preloadFilters(FilterManager.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1618)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2761)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:889)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:333)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:117)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:635)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:358)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:52)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:186)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:173)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:89)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
Caused by: Action class [Login] not found - action - file:/users/capstat/tiv/bea/user_projects/domains/UATTIV/autodeploy/xmlconversion.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:19:57
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:434)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:378)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:495)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:286)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    ... 40 more
<Nov 24, 2016 11:46:19 AM CET> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101165> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/users/capstat/tiv/bea/user_projects/domains/UATTIV/autodeploy/xmlconversion.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:19:57
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:450)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:309)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/users/capstat/tiv/bea/user_projects/domains/UATTIV/autodeploy/xmlconversion.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:19:57
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Action class [Login] not found - action - file:/users/capstat/tiv/bea/user_projects/domains/UATTIV/autodeploy/xmlconversion.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:19:57
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:434)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:378)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:495)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:286)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

What could be the possible issue in this case???

web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN' 'http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2.2.dtd'>

<web-app>

<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name> 
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class> 
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name> 
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>  

<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" /> 
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

<global-exception-mappings>  
<exception-mapping result="myresult" exception="java.lang.Exception"></exception-mapping>  
</global-exception-mappings>

<action name="loginUser" class="Login" method="execute">
<result name="input">login.jsp</result>
<result name="success">all_pages.jsp</result>
</action>

</package>  

</struts>
```

the Login.class:

```java
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Login extends ActionSupport{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
       private String password;

       public String execute() 
       {
           return SUCCESS;
       }
       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }
       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }
       public String getPassword() {
           return password;
       }
       public void setPassword(String password) {
           this.password = password;
       }

       public void validate()
       {
          if (name == null || name.trim().equals(""))
          {
             addFieldError("name","Please Provide");
          }
          if (password== null || password.trim().equals(""))
          {
             addFieldError("password","Please Provide");
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Did you upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: Which one should I upgrade to latest version @Roman C?

Comment: You can get it on http://struts.apache.org.

Comment: Hi @Roman C. Do you suggest me to proceed with downloading the Struts 2.5.5 latest release from struts.apache.org? If yes, then a small change in struts.xml's dtd from 2.3 dtd to 2.5 to be done before deploying? please correct me.

Comment: It's not a small change, see release notes.

Comment: Yes. That wasn't a small change @Roman C. To change to struts 2.5 is a big configuration change right from jdk version till completion. I got another easy approach taught. I used eclipse for web logic 9.2 workshop to build the war and deploy with proper jars in place and finally succeeded. Ideally this issue requires a double check on the jdk version used to compile/build and jdk version in the server where it's hosted. Both needs to be same version and compiled/built properly.